# No module named 'xlsxwriter'

Tags: installation, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to install xlsxwriter. I'm using VS Code. I installed two different versions of python when I set this up. When I use 'pip install xlsxwriter' it says it's successfully installed, but when I run the code it brings back the above error. (No module named 'xlsxwriter') I'm using 'import xlsxwriter'.

I've tried uninstalling it, installing wheel, and then trying to install it again, but I'm getting the same error.

How do I make sure I'm installing xlsxwriter correctly?

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to get the file to run by typing, 'python3 (file name)' but is there a way to change what vs code automatically runs? when I type, 'python --version' it comes back as 2.7.

I'm looking in the command palette, but I'm not seeing python3. I'll keep looking around online, but any help would be wonderful.